# FQL NoIndexFunctionException on indexed field

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to query the created time for a facebook link by executing the following fql question

```
SELECT created_time FROM link WHERE owner = me()
```

according to the developers documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link) the owner field is indexed but the graph api throws the following exception.

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql ",
    "type": "NoIndexFunctionException",
    "code": 604
  }
}
```

what is wrong with my query?

Comment: Works for me in the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20created_time%20FROM%20link%20WHERE%20owner%20%3D%20me()). Where did you run the query from?

Answer (score 0):

Select the **FQL Query** button above the text box on the Graph API Explorer and it works fine. The links go to the Graph API editor instead of the FQL editor, which is wrong.

[Example](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20created_time%20FROM%20link%20WHERE%20owner%20%3D%20me%28%29)